# Can’t enable the developer options of Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: settings, usb-debugging, samsung-galaxy-tab, usb-drivers

I have several time tap on “Build Number” for 7 times but it does not show any toast message and also not enable the developer options.

Where can we find the USB Driver for the Tab.

I have Samsung Galaxy Tab(GT-P1000).

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with a Samsung Galaxy S8. The screen is so slow to detect the taps that the most I can get in a row is 4, if I'm lucky. I can see the UI react to a single tap with the "ripple" effect, but it's impossible to do 7 in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked under Settings/Application for the option *Development*? If not, do that first. That option should be enabled.

Look under Development for *USB Debugging*. It may not be enabled. Go to *Settings/Wireless and Network/USB Settings* and choose *Ask on connection*.

Go back to *Settings/Application/Development*. The USB Debugging option should now be enabled.

If you're on Windows, download Samsung drivers, install them and then connect your tab.

Comment: Settings/Wireless and Network/USB Settings is also disable.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have accesibility settings enabled, specifically the magnification gestures, as this setting can prevent you from corrrectly detecting the multiple taps on the build number. Once you have it disabled, tap repeatedly until you see the message, if you still cant see it , it might be already enabled.