# Bypass “Verify your account” on Samsung Galaxy J2

Tags: factory-reset, frp

I have Samsung Galaxy J2 and I am unable to bypass "Verify your account".

[image: Google's Verify you account screen]

I have tried:

1. Installing and opening RootJunky APK from [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/127745/158208) which opened Settings, then I did a Factory reset -> Back up and Reset -> Factory data and reset
2. Rooting the device with Kingroot and installed a terminal app that has root access, though I don't know which commands to bypass this
3. Reflashing the phone with the stock firmware

Output of `mount`:

```
rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,size=456756k,nr_inodes=114189,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
/sys/kernel/debug /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=456756k,nr_inodes=114189,mode=750,gid=1000 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/secure tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=456756k,nr_inodes=114189,mode=700 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=456756k,nr_inodes=114189,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=456756k,nr_inodes=114189,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
/dev/block/platform/13540000.dwmmc0/by-name/CPEFS /cpefs ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/13540000.dwmmc0/by-name/SYSTEM /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,block_validity,norecovery 0 0
/dev/block/platform/13540000.dwmmc0/by-name/CACHE /cache ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,journal_checksum,journal_async_commit,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/13540000.dwmmc0/by-name/USERDATA /data ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,journal_checksum,journal_async_commit,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/13540000.dwmmc0/by-name/EFS /efs ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,journal_checksum,journal_async_commit,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/13540000.dwmmc0/by-name/PERSDATA /persdata/absolute ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/data/knox/secure_fs/enc_media /mnt/shell/enc_media sdcardfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,derive=none,reserved=20MB 0 0
/data/knox/sdcard /mnt/shell/knox-emulated sdcardfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,derive=none 0 0
/data/media /mnt/shell/emulated sdcardfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,derive=legacy,reserved=20MB 0 0
tmpfs /storage/emulated tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=751,gid=1028 0 0
/data/media /storage/emulated/0 sdcardfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,derive=legacy,reserved=20MB 0 0
/data/media /storage/emulated/legacy sdcardfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,derive=legacy,reserved=20MB 0 0
```

output of `ls -l /dev/block/platform/13540000.dwmmc0/by-name/`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 BOOT -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p10
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 BOTA0 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 BOTA1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p2
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 CACHE -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p21
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 CARRIER -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p8
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 CDMA-RADIO -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p13
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 CPEFS -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p4
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 EFS -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p3
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 HIDDEN -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p22
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 OTA -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p12
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 PARAM -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p9
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 PERSDATA -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p18
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 PERSISTENT -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p17
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 RADIO -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p14
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 RECOVERY -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p11
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 RESERVED2 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p19
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 SYSTEM -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p20
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 TDATA -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p16
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 TOMBSTONES -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p15
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 USERDATA -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p23
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 m9kefs1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p5
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 m9kefs2 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p6
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-28 16:01 m9kefs3 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p7
```

512KB partition

[image]

Comment: A factory reset from settings should not result in this issue, only a factory reset from recovery. Also, Samsung devices have a nonstandard partition layout, so the linked answer might not help. You could try the ADB steps, though. Run this in the terminal and tell me if it allows you to get into settings: `content insert --uri content://settings/secure --bind name:s:user_setup_complete --bind value:s:1` Thanks to @MatthewRead for including this in his answer in the link

Comment: Since you've no problem in getting into Settings app, can you try adding a Google account there and then removing it? Removing the account shall disable FRP per this article: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00042882/99737975And in the Settings app, under Developer options do you see an option OEM Unlock? If yes, enable it and do a factory reset. You've to first enable Developer options. See http://www.recovery-android.com/enable-usb-debugging-on-android.html for that.

Comment: @Firelord  Tapping the build number 7 times does not enable Developer options. I've also been though [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/123749/158208).  Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37616/discussion-between-neil-and-firelord).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I had to sign in to the original account through the help of RootJunky APK, went to Settings -> Account, and added the original Google account and it verified it that way. It might be because it skips checking the connection.